# In context of graph search,what is mini-max principle

Tags: algorithms

after doing some Google search i am not able to find an effective and understandable explanation of mini-max principle,anyone please explain it to me.

Answer (score -1):

***MINIMAX PRINCIPLE***
Minimax is a method in decision theory for minimizing the xpected maximum loss. It is  applied in two players games such as tic-tac-toe, or chess where the two players take alternate moves. It has also been extended to more complex games whic require general decision making in the presence of increased uncertainty. All these games have a common property that they are logic games. This means that these games can be described by a set of rules and premises. So it is possible to know at a given point of time, what are the next available moves.